# How to make a nested for loop using a generator in python?

Tags: python, syntax, nested, generator, bioinformatics

I'm trying to convert this nested for loop:

```
        for k,v in all_R.iteritems():
            for pairs in v:
                print pairs[1]
```

to a one liner, something like this:

```
print ([pairs[1] for pairs in v for k,v in all_R.iteritems()])
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
```

all_R is a defaultdict where every value has keys that are pairs, and I'm interested in just one value from that pair:

```
     {'1-0002': [('A-75G', 'dnaN'), ('I245T', 'recF'),... ], '1-0004': [('A-75G', 'dnaN'), ('L161', 'dnaN'),...]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List comprehensions are written in the same order as for loops, so you are actually looking for (Note the order is reversed)

```py
([pairs[1] for k,v in all_R.iteritems() for pairs in v ])
```

Here's a break down that shows the structure a bit more clearly:

```py
[
    pairs[1]
        for k,v in all_R.iteritems()
            for pairs in v
]
```

If you are looking to use generators as your title suggests, you can use parenthesis instead of brackets.

```py
(pairs[1] for k,v in all_R.iteritems() for pairs in v)
```

That will create a generator with your desired properties.